# How to create a textbox in Gui that can hold my print statements?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to make a texted based game where I ask the user a series of questions similar to how a survey works. I want to make a GUI with a box where these questions can be asked and another box so that they can input their answers. I've researched this a bit but i'm not sure how to get the text they input as an answer because depending on how they answer the question, a different action occurs. So my question is how to create a text box that can hold my print statements and another text box where the user can input answers.

Comment: Which framework? Swing/JavaFX/SWT/GWT/Web...?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing: for your questions you can use a `JLabel` and set the text in it either through the constructor or through its `setText()` method.

As for user answers you can use a `JTextField` or `JTextArea` object (depending on the expected size of user input) and call the `getText()` methods to retrieve the user input as a String.

Answer (score 0):

print statements print the output to the console not to the application, so what you can do is replace the print statements with the `loadQuestion()` function.

```
public void LoadQuestion(String question)
   {
    label1.setText(question);//label1 is the questions label which sets the string question to the label
   }

//==setting up the labels
JButton answerButton;
JPanel panel;
JLabel label1,label2;
final JTextField text2;
JLabel scoreLabel;
int score = 0;
Quiz()
 {
   label1 = new JLabel();
   label1.setText("Questions:");//questions label
   scoreLabel = new JLabel("SCORE: ");
   label2 = new JLabel();
   label2.setText("Answer:");//answer label
   text2 = new JTextField(15);//answer textfield
   answerButton=new JButton("ANSWER");
   panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
   panel.add(scoreLabel);
   panel.add(label1);
   panel.add(label2);
   panel.add(text2);
   panel.add(answerButton);
   add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   answerButton.addActionListener(this);
   setTitle("QUIZ");
}
```

SetUp your UI.

- A Score Label which maintains score.
- A Questions Label which has the question to display.
- An Answer TextBox which takes the answer from the user.
- A submit button which validates the answer.

Add Actions to your button, take the text from the answer box and validate.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
   {
   String answer =text2.getText();
    if(answer.equals(" "))
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Correct Answer");
    score++;
    scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: "+score);
    } 
   else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Wrong Answer");
     scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: "+score);
   }
 }
```

The total code for the Application is here:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Quiz extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {
  JButton answerButton;
  JPanel panel;
  JLabel label1,label2;
  final JTextField text2;
  JLabel scoreLabel;
  int score = 0;
   Quiz()
   {
   label1 = new JLabel();
   label1.setText("Questions:");//questions label
   scoreLabel = new JLabel("SCORE: ");

   label2 = new JLabel();
   label2.setText("Answer:");//answer label
   text2 = new JTextField(15);//answer textfield

   answerButton=new JButton("ANSWER");

   panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
   panel.add(scoreLabel);
   panel.add(label1);

   panel.add(label2);
   panel.add(text2);
   panel.add(answerButton);
   add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   answerButton.addActionListener(this);
   setTitle("QUIZ");
   }

   public void LoadQuestion(String question)
   {
    label1.setText(question);
   }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
   {
   String answer =text2.getText();
    if(answer.equals(" "))
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Correct Answer");
    score++;
    scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: "+score);
    } 
   else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Wrong Answer");
     scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: "+score);
   }
 }
 }
  class QuizDemo
 {
   public static void main(String arg[])
   {
   try
   {
   Quiz frame=new Quiz();
   frame.setSize(300,100);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());}
   }
 }
```

**EDIT**

Setting Answers

As soon as you load a question set an answer for it, compare it when the user clicks the answer button, If it is the same then `correct` else a `wrong` answer.

Comment: Are the arrays here necessary? Would it work if I didn't create any arrays because I have all of my questions already in a System.out.print format and i don't want to go through the hassle to put them all into an array. And i'm unsure what the purpose of creating new jbuttons for generating questions and I would appreciate it if you explained to me why you included this in your answer, which i appreciate greatly.

Comment: also should this be incorporated into my driver class? I'm also getting an error that says cannot find symbol - class ActionListener. Could you help me with this certain issue?

Comment: @johnnguyen I have edited the answer for you, If you want any more functionalities feel free to ask

Comment: How do you change the questions from this? I don't know how to add my questions into this application. I tried using Quiz.LoadQuestion("What is your name?") but that gives me a static constant error.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you reply asap.

Comment: nevermind I got it working, I should've used frame.LoadQuestion. I'll get back to you asap

Comment: How do I set the answers?

Comment: Also, How do i make it so that once they give the correct answer ( which I do not  know how to set the answer ) the question changes to a new question with a new answer?